# Меню Bootstrap: сворачивание

Tags: menu, bootstrap, css

На сколько я заметил, что при сужении окна браузера, верхнее меню, при достижении определенной ширины окна, принимает вид "мобильного" меню, то есть название сайта и выпадающий список.
Но моё меню, при уменьшении ширины окна вначале принимает двухстрочный вид, а потом уже мобильный =(

Где в CSS прописывается ширина, при которой меню принимает мобильный вид?

Comment: `брайзера` спасибо, в избранное

Answer (score 1):

Мобильный вид меню принимает при разрешении 767 пикселей, до 768 пикселей идет обычный вид.
Что именно подразумеваете под "двухсточный вид" ?
Мобильный вид меню примет только при использовании структуры, как показано [здесь](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). Покажите сайт.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете самостоятельно настроить все необходимые параметры бутстрапа, а затем скачать его и подключить.
В данном случае даю ссылку с якорем сразу на нужное место.

[Customize and Download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints)

После установки всех изменений, прокрутите страницу вниз и скачивайте свою версию бутстрапа.